# Find({ example: { $elemMatch: { $eq: userId } } }).. in Aggregate - is it possible?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, match, aggregate

```
database:
[{to_match: [ userID_1, userId_2 ], data: [{...}] },
{to_match: [ userID_1, userId_2, userId_3 ], data: [{...}] },
{to_match: [ ], data: [{...}] }]
```

1. Find by an element in the array 'to-match'.

Current solution:

```
Replacement.find(
   { applicants: { $elemMatch: { $eq: userId_1 } } },
```

2. Aggregate $lookup on the result of 1.
   a. Can I Find and Aggregate?
   b. Should I first Aggregate and then match ??

   - if yes, how to match on the element in the array?

I tried Aggregate:

```
$lookup // OK
{ $match: { applicants: { $in: { userId } } } } // issues
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use $lookup and $match in aggregate

Instead of $in use $elemMatch like below:

```
{ $match: { applicants:  { $elemMatch: { $eq: userId_1 }  } } }
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing an $elemMatch on just one field is equivalent to using find([link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition))

Generally, it is efficient to limit the data that the lookup stage will be working on.
So if I understand correctly, you want to filter the "to_match" array elements and then do a lookup on that result.

Here is what I would suggest:-

```
    aggregate([
    {
        $project : {
            to_match: {
                    $filter: {
                           input: "$to_match",
                           as: "item",
                           cond: { $eq: [ "$$item", "userId_3" ] }
                        }
            },
            data : 1
        }
    },
    {
        $match : { "to_match" : {$ne : []}}
    },
    //// Lookup stage here
])
```

Based on the field that you want to do a lookup on, you may want to unwind this result.

Comment: Thank you, I found the method using .aggregate after .distinct. Your proposition looks promising but I couldn't just paste it, it returns an empty array. I will take some course of mongoDb beside work, as it takes too much time trying all the time..